# Data type conversion function using reflection

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a map which stores keys and values as String data type.
I need to write a function which would convert certain values in the map from String data type to another data type.

For e.g., there is a key `"active"` and value `"false"`. I need to convert the value to `boolean false`.

For this , I can have a function like this:

```
public static void typeConverter(Map container, String key, Class toType) {
    if(container.containsKey(key)) {
        if(tyType == Boolean.class)
            container.put(key, Boolean.parseBoolean(container.get(key)));
        if(tyType == Integer.class)
            container.put(key, Integer.parseBoolean(container.get(key)));
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I would like to use reflection and avoid the if loops:

```
public static void typeConverter(Map container, String key, Class toType) {
    if(container.containsKey(key))
        container.put(key, toType.parse*(container.get(key)));
}
```

Is this possible by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing in the Class object, do you know which type you'd like it to become when you call typeConverter(...)?
If so, you could pass in an object to do the conversion and return the desired type.

```
public interface Converter<R>
{
     public R convert(String value);
}
```

Create subclasses of a concrete type

```
public class IntConverter implements Converter<Integer>
{
    public Integer convert(String value) { ... }
}
```

Then call typeConverter, and pass it the correct converter.

```
public static void typeConverter(Map container, String key, Converter<?> converter) {
    if(container.containsKey(key)) {
        return converter.convert(container.get(key));
   }
}
```

Comment: I think adding if loops like I provided in my code is better than this approach since here I need to implement interfaces instead of a single line in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the possible value type are primitive type, the method **valueOf** exists for all primitive type such as Integer, Boolean...
So you can use reflexion to invoke this method dynamically.

```
public static void convert(Map container, String key, Class toType) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    Method method=toType.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
    if(container.containsKey(key)){
        container.put(key, method.invoke(toType, container.get(key)));
    }
}
```

Or you can also take the parser method name as parameter to your function and the result will be

```
public static void convert(Map container, String key, Class toType, String parserMethodName) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    Method method=toType.getMethod(parserMethodName, String.class);
    if(container.containsKey(key)){
        container.put(key, method.invoke(toType, container.get(key)));
    }
}
```

And this will work for any type, as far as the parser Method is able to convert the String to the target type.